# Reduce to Beta Form Verification

Tags: lambda-calculus

What is the normal form of the following lambda term? I'm stuck between two answers and I just wanted to know which one is correct.

$$\lambda y. (\lambda x.x)\ y$$

Possible Answer 1: $\lambda x.x$
Possible Answer 2: $\lambda y.y$

Comment: What do you think is the correct answer and why?

Comment: Possible answer 3: $\lambda z.z$

Comment: These two answers are alpha convertible, so they are usually regarded as "the same". Personally, I'd never ask such a question offering those as two possible answers.

Comment: @chi It's unclear but I'd assumed that the asker had produced two answers himself and wasn't sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 2):

The two terms you've come up with are $\alpha$-equivalent – they're thesame except for the names of the variables. Normally, $\alpha$-equivalent terms are considered to be the same thing so, without knowing anything more about the situation, both of your possible answers seem to be correct.